# Python Hailstone sequence with only 10 outputs per line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a positive integer n, the following rules will always create a sequence that ends with 1, called the hailstone sequence:

- If n is even, divide it by 2
- If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1 (i.e. 3n +1)
- Continue until n is 1

Write a program that reads an integer as input and prints the hailstone sequence starting with the integer entered. Format the output so that ten integers, each separated by a tab character (\t), are printed per line.

The output format can be achieved as follows:
print(n, end='\t')

Ex: If the input is:

```
25
```

the output is:

```
25   76   38   19   58   29   88   44   22   11 
34   17   52   26   13   40   20   10   5    16 
8    4    2    1
```

I tried this and I'm getting the right result, but in the wrong format since the question says we need to output only 10 results per line. I can't find anything online saying how to do this. I put in extra code to eliminate the space after the final "1" output since my grading program was counting it as an error.

```
n = int(input())
print(n, end='\t')
while n > 2:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * n + 1
        print(n, end='\t')
    else:
        n = n // 2
        print(n, end='\t')
if n == 2:
    n = n // 2
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter, that counts the increment in the while loop. Also by setting the good condition `while n != 1` you don't need the extra code at the end

```
print(n, end='\t')
count = 1
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    else:
        n = n // 2

    count += 1
    print(n, end='\n' if count % 10 == 0 else '\t')
```